# Concatenate macro with string

Tags: macros, expansion, etoolbox

I try to expand a macro containing a string with another string. It is in the document and thus I want to avoid using `@`.

I tried the following using `etoolbox`

```
\expandafter\def\fileAcronym\democodefile
\appto\fileAcronym{-acronym}
```

It does not work. The `\demcocodefile` is not expanded (thus the `\expandafter`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're expanding is `\fileAcronym` and not `\democodefile`, since `\expandafter` *expands* whatever comes immediately *after* the next token. You could use

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\fileAcronym\expandafter{\democodefile}
\appto\fileAcronym{-acronym}
```

but it may be more concise (since you're only using strings) to rather use

```
\edef\fileAcronym{\democodefile-acronym}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `\democodefile` expands to the string you want to append something to, creating `\fileAcronym` that expands to the augmented string, the easiest way is to say

```
\let\fileAcronym\democodefile
\appto\fileAcronym{-acronym}
```

Without `\appto`:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\fileAcronym\expandafter{\democodefile-acronym}
```

With less characters

```
\edef\fileAcronym{\unexpanded\expandafter{\democodefile}-acronym}
```

(`\unexpanded\expandafter` can be replaced by `\expandonce`, if you already load `etoolbox`).

---

An “abstract” version:

```
\newcommand{\augmentstring}[3]{%
    \edef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#2}\unexpanded{#3}}%
}
```

With that code in the preamble you can say, in the document,

```
\augmentstring{\fileAcronym}{\democode}{-acronym}
```